# How to get name from method-wrapper, builtin_function_or_method types for inspect.getmembers predicate

Tags: python, reflection, python-2.7

I am attempting to write a predicate function for the [inspect.getmembers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) method so that I can get a list of properties in an object.

But I can't seem to find a way to get the name of any of the objects that are passed to the predicate function. In the example below I can see the types of the objects being passed to the function

```
In [12]: from __future__ import print_function

In [13]: inspect.getmembers('', lambda x: print(x))
<method-wrapper '__add__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
<type 'str'>
<method-wrapper '__contains__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
<method-wrapper '__delattr__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
str(object='') -> string

Return a nice string representation of the object.
If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
<method-wrapper '__eq__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
<built-in method __format__ of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
<method-wrapper '__ge__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
<method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
<method-wrapper '__getitem__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
<built-in method __getnewargs__ of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
<method-wrapper '__getslice__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>
...

In [14]: inspect.getmembers('', lambda x: print(type(x)))
<type 'method-wrapper'>
<type 'type'>
<type 'method-wrapper'>
<type 'method-wrapper'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'method-wrapper'>
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
<type 'method-wrapper'>
<type 'method-wrapper'>
<type 'method-wrapper'>
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
<type 'method-wrapper'>
...
```

But I don't know how to get just the name from that object, it doesn't seem to expose any normal methods

```
In [15]: exampleMethod = inspect.getmembers('')[20]

In [17]: print(exampleMethod)
('__ne__', <method-wrapper '__ne__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>)

In [18]: exampleMethod = exampleMethod[1]

In [19]: print(exampleMethod)
<method-wrapper '__ne__' of str object at 0x0000000001D67148>

In [20]: dir(exampleMethod)
Out[20]:
['__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__cmp__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__name__',
 '__new__',
 '__objclass__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__self__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']  

In [21]: exampleMethod.name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-09eecffac362> in <module>()
----> 1 exampleMethod.name

AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can I get `__ne__` from exampleMethod or any of the other types passed into the predicate? `exampleMethod.__name__` works for that example, but not for all of the types

```
In [23]: inspect.getmembers('', lambda x: print(x.__name__))
__add__
str
__contains__
__delattr__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-0e3fe501926e> in <module>()
----> 1 inspect.getmembers('', lambda x: print(x.__name__))

C:\Anaconda\lib\inspect.pyc in getmembers(object, predicate)
    254         except AttributeError:
    255             continue
--> 256         if not predicate or predicate(value):
    257             results.append((key, value))
    258     results.sort()

<ipython-input-23-0e3fe501926e> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 inspect.getmembers('', lambda x: print(x.__name__))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `__name__` instead. It *is* listed in your exploratory output for `exampleMethod`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers('')[20]
('__ne__', <method-wrapper '__ne__' of str object at 0x10bbb2508>)
>>> inspect.getmembers('')[20][1].__name__
'__ne__'
```

Almost members have that attribute; the only exception is the `__doc__` string:

```
>>> [getattr(o, '__name__', None) for n, o in inspect.getmembers('')]
['__add__', 'str', '__contains__', '__delattr__', None, '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

For `__doc__` the predicate **cannot** access the attribute name; the predicate only has access to the value, *not* the attribute name under which it is stored, and strings never have name of their own.